# What is the main difference between the SessionAwareCoreServiceClient to the CoreServiceClient?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

What is the main difference between the SessionAwareCoreServiceClient to the CoreServiceClient?

Is wsHttp the preferred binding from a remote application not running on the server?  Is it possible to use the netTcp binding from a remote Core Service application? Why not?

The Tridion Core Service gives us 3 main bindings to use for XML content:

- netTcp - Fastest
- wsHttp - Uses ws* standards and is better than basicHttp
- basicHttp - backwards compatible to .NET 2.0

I found this article about the [differences between wsHttp and basicHttp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind).  Also a nice explanation of why [netTcp is faster in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500030/wcf-nettcpbinding-vs-httpbinding-difference-in-data-sent-on-wire)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to use netTcp for remote client if only port 2660 is open (keep in mind it might be tricky to configure LDAP).

wsHttp has some advantages, like `Impersonate` and is more secure then basicHttp.

netTcp is the best as it is the most secure, can impersonate and is fastest of all by big margin. The only problem is that it's running on different port for now.

There's also possibility to have netTcp in IIS 7, but as Tridion 2011 still support windows 2003 (IIS 6 which can't do netTcp) there's no netTcp endpoint in IIS. It might be added for the next release.